# Question to find equation of curve using differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Q: The equation of a curve such that the projection of its ordinate upon the normal is equal to its abscissa is?

---

My doubt: The phrase "projection of ordinate upon normal" is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that I well understand the wording.

On the figure below : The curve (C) represents the function $y(x)$.

At point P$(x,y)$ on (C), the tangent is (T) and the normal is (N) :
$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

OB=y. The orthogonal projection of OB on (N) is EF.

$$\text{EF=BH=OB}\cos(\theta)=y\cos(\theta)$$

The condition $\quad$EF=OA=$x\quad$ leads to the next ODE :
$$\begin{cases}
y\cos(\theta)=x \\
\tan(\theta)=\frac{dy}{dx}
\end{cases} \quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2}-1}
$$

[image]

The solution of the ODE can be given on the form of an implicit equation :

[image]